# Adding subversion commit hooks for all repositories

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I have a subversion installation with one repository per project and would like to add a few commit hooks that should apply for all the repositories. Is there any way to add a hook for all repositories? Especially in such a way that when I add a new repository these hooks also apply automatically?
I can only find ways to do this on a per-repository basis.

Answer (score 5):

Hooks can only be set up per repository. I usually have a folder where hooks are stored and use a batch file with a loop to copy them to the repositories.

To do this easily create a folder `templates` in the SvnParentPath (the root folder of your repositories) where you put your hooks

Then create a batch file containing the following code (change the `%%` to `%` to run this directly on the command line.):

```
    FOR /D %%I in (*) DO copy .\templates\*.* %%I\hooks\ /Y
```

Comment: That's a solution I also had in mind, it's probably the only way there is. Do you have any example code maybe?

Comment: added an example to the answer.